# Double foreach with html collective and pluck

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in database I have products with custom features and custom feature values. For example product has a "wood type" and option value "oak". Each feature and feature value could have translations.

In database I have:

```
features 
- id
- few other fields (no matter)

feature_langs
- id_feature
- id_lang
- name

feature_values
- id
- few other fieds (no matter)

feature_value_langs
- id_feature_value
- id_lang
- name
```

And now in product edition I use htmlCollective and display 40x selects with multiple options and it looks like this:
[image]

Problem is that with features loading page takes 1-1,8s randomly. Without that loading is close to 500-600ms.

For db query I use simply:

```
$features = Feature::with('translation')->get();
$featureValues = FeatureValue::with('translation')->get();
```

And form displaying:

```
    @forelse($features as $feature)
       <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
           <label class="col-2 col-form-label">{{ $feature->getName() }}</label>
           <div class="col-5">
{!! Form::select('featureValue',$featureValues->where('id_feature',$feature->id)->map(function ($setting) {
     return ['key' => $setting->getName(), 'value' => $setting->id];
    })->pluck('key', 'value')->prepend('Choose', '')->toArray(), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
           </div>
           </div>
   @empty
      No data
   @endforelse
```

Is there some bottleneck or I am missing something?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Have you measured your DB queries time? Is it not too big?

Comment: Debug bar shows -  15 statements were executed 77.49ms (there are many other elements on product edition page).  30MB memory usage. Timeline show delay on application part Booting (145.47ms) Application (1.43s)

Comment: What can I advice you - start measuring you application execution time. There is a const `LARAVEL_START` inside `index.php`, you can check how long does it take to execute your code somewhere in your methods by subtracting current microtime and `LARAVEL_START`

Comment: Thanks for help. I've checked code few times. Controller takes 400ms~ so i've looked into view part. After cutting lag causing part is above - displaying features values. Probably map function  makes code rendering slow.

Comment: Try to move data processing from PHP to MySQL, it'll faster your app